# How do I import a text file so that it becomes the body text of my LaTeX document?

Tags: import, external-files

I want to completely separate formatting and content creation. The articles I will write are all plain prose that requires minimum or zero LaTeX formatting.

Also, the text file doesn't have the **one-blank-line gap** between paragraphs. They are separated only by one linefeed.

**SUMMARY:**
Is there a way to import it roughly like:

```
\begin{document}
  \importtextfile{my_essay.txt}
\end{document}
```

Can I also tell LaTeX to interpret the *single* linefeeds as *new paragraph*?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure. TeX inserts (by default) `^^M` at the end of each line. So something like

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M\active
\let ^^M\par%
\input{youressay.txt}%
\endgroup%
```

should do it, although I didn't test.

Edit: I just remembered the `\obeylines` macro which does exactly what I wrote above.

```
\begingroup
\obeylines
\input{youressay.txt}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: +1. By default, this won't indent the first line of the text file.  However, you can use `\usepackage{indentfirst}` in the preamble.  This might come in handy when you have content split out into different text files.