# Replace spaces/tabs in an imported .txt file upon import?

Tags: external-files, import

I read the answers to this question: [Import a text file into LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1614), and am now wondering if it's possible to let TeX replace tabs or spaces in that text-file with `&` for example if you export some data in comma or tab separated values from another source.

I do realize that it's simple to do that in any any text editor, but it would be convenient if some changes needed to be done on the source, not having to modify that text file over and over after exporting.

Comment: If you can export your data as comma-separated values, then you may try using the [csvtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/csvtools) package.

Comment: @mpg isn't datatool the successor to cvstools?

Comment: @Will Yeah it seems so. This seems to be the solution to that problem. Doesn't it qualify as an answer? Or might there be other ways of doing this?

Comment: Alternatively, with `write18` enabled might you be able to do some `awk` magic on the file before inputting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `fifinddo` package, but its documentation isn't exactly obvious to me so I can't give you a minimal example `:)` I think you want §4 for details on how to use the package.